# Hyper-V 2008 R2 Core system hangs on Applying computer setting for 3 hours

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I have a standalone Hyper-V 2008 R2 server with 3 guests running on it.

After the reboot of the physical server it hangs on "Applying computer settings" for 3 hours. After that you get a chance to login but then again it hangs on "Applying user settings" for about 30 minutes to 1 hour.

Once you have logged in, even from safe mode, I do not get to see the Sconfig commands, it's just an empty Windows.

It does not matter how the server reboots, I still can't get the VM to start.

I have tried these things:

- Started server with no network (which makes the boot faster but
  I still can't see anything for SConfig)
- Started in safe mode (still same problem as above).

I do not know what to do now. This has happened to other servers too and the only solution I have found up to now is to rebuild the Hyper-V 2008 R2 core server.

Comment: Are these servers joined to an Active Directory domain? If so, what do these servers use for DNS?

Comment: What group policies are applied to these servers? What do the application and system event logs indicate?

Comment: @joeqwerty server is join to domain. DNS server was also done

Comment: @Goatmale check the events but they was not much info

Comment: Spoken with MS, they dont know what is causeing this issue so at the end I rebuild the server and recover the vms from vhd's